Converting Stata file version 69
I have a very large number of stata .dta file version 69 files that I need to convert into .csv or some other excel readable format. I should note that I only know how to get the version number from the pandas error message, but opening it as a text file shows something very different from a modern stata 118 file so I suspect that it isn't just an issue of the version number getting misencoded.
Methods tried so far (file type not supported):

Python pandas library
R foreign library
R rio library

Here is my pandas code:
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_stata('3-charge.DTA')
data.to_csv('3-charge.csv')

And the stacktrace:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 3
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 3 data = pd.read_stata('3-charge.DTA')
      4 data.to_csv('3-charge.csv')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\stata.py:2150, in read_stata(filepath_or_buffer, convert_dates, convert_categoricals, index_col, convert_missing, preserve_dtypes, columns, order_categoricals, chunksize, iterator, compression, storage_options)
   2147     return reader
   2149 with reader:
-> 2150     return reader.read()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\stata.py:1708, in StataReader.read(self, nrows, convert_dates, convert_categoricals, index_col, convert_missing, preserve_dtypes, columns, order_categoricals)
   1696 @Appender(_read_method_doc)
   1697 def read(
   1698     self,
   (...)
   1706     order_categoricals: bool | None = None,
   1707 ) -> DataFrame:
-> 1708     self._ensure_open()
   1710     # Handle options
   1711     if convert_dates is None:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\stata.py:1182, in StataReader._ensure_open(self)
   1178 """
   1179 Ensure the file has been opened and its header data read.
   1180 """
   1181 if not hasattr(self, "_path_or_buf"):
-> 1182     self._open_file()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\stata.py:1212, in StataReader._open_file(self)
   1209         self._path_or_buf = BytesIO(handles.handle.read())
   1210     self._close_file = self._path_or_buf.close
-> 1212 self._read_header()
   1213 self._setup_dtype()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\stata.py:1294, in StataReader._read_header(self)
   1292     self._read_new_header()
   1293 else:
-> 1294     self._read_old_header(first_char)
   1296 self._has_string_data = len([x for x in self._typlist if type(x) is int]) > 0
   1298 # calculate size of a data record

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\stata.py:1473, in StataReader._read_old_header(self, first_char)
   1471 self._format_version = int(first_char[0])
   1472 if self._format_version not in [104, 105, 108, 111, 113, 114, 115]:
-> 1473     raise ValueError(_version_error.format(version=self._format_version))
   1474 self._set_encoding()
   1475 self._byteorder = ">" if self._read_int8() == 0x1 else "<"

ValueError: Version of given Stata file is 69. pandas supports importing versions 105, 108, 111 (Stata 7SE), 113 (Stata 8/9), 114 (Stata 10/11), 115 (Stata 12), 117 (Stata 13), 118 (Stata 14/15/16),and 119 (Stata 15/16, over 32,767 variables).

There is a method given in this post that seems to have worked, but unfortunately I am very new to this sort of thing and it went over my head. (And I am new enough to stack overflow that I can't comment to ask for clarification)
If someone could give me a very beginner friendly explanation of the above method, or has another method that works with files that old, I would greatly appreciate it.

In R, you can try the haven package (the foreign package is not maintained anymore).

Unfortunately it's giving me a failed to parse, version not supported error as well. Thanks for the suggestion though

The current version of Stata is ~18.5, so my bet (especially given your solution below), is that these may not be Stata files at all.

Not all .dta files are Stata data. You are trying to open something which has nothing to do with Stata.

Managed to find a solution! This Python package converts the files into something readable by pandas. I think that file type 69 might be an instrument-specific file type rather than a very old one.

While the information in your link may solve your question, answers that rely heavily on links are discouraged for these reasons. Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained, with the minimum amount of code and instructions required to demonstrate how it works. Thanks
